# How to implement a click event for a stackpanel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visibility, stackpanel

I checked the stackpanel class here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx and it has no click event.

I'm working on a windows phone 8 app and I've got a textbox and some buttons on a stack panel. I want to include a feature where the stackpanel can be clicked then the visibility of the controls on it are set to collapsed, and then when clicked again they become visible.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem in a little tricky manner, if it is good then it's ok otherwise i'll Post the another one.

```
 <StackPanel Background="Red" MinHeight="80"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Tap="StackPanel_Tap_1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="Button"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn2" Content="Button"/>
            <TextBox Height="72" x:Name="textbox1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="456"/>
        </StackPanel> 




 private void StackPanel_Tap_1(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {


        if (btn1.IsEnabled==false)
        {
            btn1.IsEnabled = true;
            btn1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            btn2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            textbox1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {

            btn1.IsEnabled = false;
            btn1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            btn2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            textbox1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Since this question was for WP8, it has nothing to do with WPF.

Answer (score 10):

Try using the [`MouseLeftButtonUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttonup.aspx) event.

Comment: StackPanel.MouseLeftButtonDown worked for a simple Silverlight UserControl.

Answer (score 9):

You could just wrap the whole stackpanel in a button:

```
<button>
    <stackpanel>
    </stackpanel>
</button>
```

Then attach a click event or command to the button as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

put the `StackPanel` inside the `Border` control, use `MouseLeftButtonUp` of the `Border` to handle event and set background of the `Border` to `#000001`

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the `TouchUp` and `TouchDown` event.
But I think you have to check if the `TouchDown` is on the same `StackPanel` as the `TouchUp`. So you can check if it was a "click".