# Doing onclick on stackpanel (Window Phone 7.0)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, onclick, stackpanel

How can I do a onclick on the stackpanel inside a list ?? I have a list of data that is retrieve from the WCF service. My current codes are below:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="Results" Height="450" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,20"  >
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding SearchVal}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I have went to a lot website to research, I tired mouse cannot, Tap, Up a lot more..

I have used the codes you provided, but inside the ItemTapped, I have no button, so I change to button to the TextBlock. But it wont work.

```
//I try changing button to TextBlock, wont work.
var selectedSearchBtn = sender as Button; //Assuming your trigger is a button UI element. 

        if (selectedSearchBtn != null)
        {
            var selectedVal = selectedSearchBtn.DataContext as TestMap.Classes.Global.Place;
            Classes.Global.searchedValue = "Test to get into the loop in main";

            if (selectedVal != null)
            {
                Classes.Global.posy = selectedVal.Y;
                Classes.Global.posx = selectedVal.X;

            }

            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698723/how-to-implement-a-click-event-for-a-stackpanel)

```
<ListBox x:Name="Results" Height="450" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,20" Tap="ItemTapped">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SearchVal}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

private void ItemTapped(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = sender as FrameworkElement; //

        if (element != null)
        {
            var selectedVal = element.DataContext as TestMap.Classes.Global.Place;
            Classes.Global.searchedValue = "Test to get into the loop in main";

            if (selectedVal != null)
            {
                Classes.Global.posy = selectedVal.Y;
                Classes.Global.posx = selectedVal.X;

            }

            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried the tapped method, behind the ItemTapped what should I do from the previous code ? as previously was button. Check out the updates above =)

Comment: Updated, Most UI controls inherit from a Framework element type, I've cast it into a framework element so that it would work for your buttons, stackpanels etc.